# rails URL rewriting using

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-routing

How to rewrite below URL

```
127.0.0.1:3000/article/index?type=1
```

as

```
127.0.0.1:3000/article/category/brand
```

where type 1 is category with name brand.

is it possible using rails?

route.rb

```
get "article/index"
```

article_controller.rb

```
def index
  @article =  Article.find(params[:type])
end
```

article.rb //model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
end
```

link to this route

```
<%= link_to category.name, {:controller => "article", :action => "index", :type => category.id }%>
```

Comment: Share your routes.rb, article and category model, and view code as well.

Comment: please check updated code above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails doesn't provide what you are trying to achieve out of the box. Here I give you some suggestions to get you where you wanted to go.

1. routes.rb

```rb
get "articles/category/:id" => "articles#index", as: "articles_by_category"
```

As such nothing wrong with your configuration but not a good practice. Learn more about it [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions)

2. models/article.rb - leave as is
3. Use https://github.com/norman/friendly_id Gem. Follow usage guide https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#usage to install and configure it.
4. models/category.rb

```rb
class Category < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :articles
end
```

5. ```
   <%= link_to category.name, articles_by_category_path(category.id) %>
   ```
6. article_controller.rb

```rb
def index
  @articles = Category.friendly.find(params[:id]).articles
end
```

P.S. the assumption here is there will be multiple articles for given category.